# python argparse: print epilog only when verbose

Tags: python, argparse

I define a parser with a description, options, and an epilog. When I run the app with --help, it outputs help with the epilog as expected. However, I only want to see the epilog if --help is accompanied with --verbose. What is the proper way to achieve this with argparse?

```
# example code in file test
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description='description', epilog='epilog' )
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='verbose help')
parser.parse_args()
```

When I run test as follows

```
$ python test -h
```

it yields

```
 usage: test [-h] [-v]

description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose help

epilog
```

However, what I want to see is

```
 usage: test [-h] [-v]

description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose help
```

with the epilog shown only when I run

```
$ python test -h -v
```

Comment: Try these ideas in an interactive Python session.  You can look at the `parser` object and its attributes.  You can test `parser.format_help()` without exiting.  You can try inputs with `args=parser.parse_args([...])`.  In a good one like `Ipython` you can also look at the code for various methods and functions.  Otherwise look at the `argparse.py` file.

Comment: agree, that sounds like a good approach.  or you could also use the debugger and step through the code from parse_args call on.  a solution might be to figure out which methods are relevant to your problem and subclass `argparse.ArgumentParser` appropriately.  depending on how it is put together, that might be only a minor tweak on your end and it would cover unexpected ways to invoke help and verbose mode.

Answer (score 2):

Ick.  The only way I know of doing this is by writing the help output by yourself:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( 
  description='description', 
  add_help=False )
parser.add_argument(
  '-h', '--help',
  action=store_true,
  dest='show_help')   
parser.add_argument(
  '-v', '--verbose', 
  action='store_true', 
  help='verbose help')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.show_help:
  if args.verbose:
    print '%s\n%s' % (parser.format_help(), 'epilog')
  else
    parser.print_help()
  sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: The limitation of this approach is that epilog cannot have things like %(prog)s.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideas suggested, here's what I came up with:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description='description', epilog='', add_help=False )
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='store_true', help='show help')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='more help')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.help:
    if args.verbose:
        parser.epilog += "epilog for %(prog)s"
    else:
        parser.epilog += "\nfor more help run '%(prog)s -h -v'"
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit(0)

print 'the end'
```

The only difficulty I found with this approach is that it is no longer possible to add required options or positional arguments. A workaround for positional arguments is to use nargs='?' and do the checking manually.

Answer (score 1):

There's no provision in `argparse` for this.  So you will have to write your own code to change the `epilog` before parsing, or perform your own `help` after parsing, or conceivably modifying the `format_help` method.

You can view and change the `epilog` attribute of the parser after creation.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(epilog='test')
print parser.epilog  # should see 'test'
parser.epilog = None # or ''
```

One deleted answer suggested looking at `sys.argv` before parsing, and if the `--verbose` is present, modify the the `epilog` attribute.  That may miss some ways of specifying the value (e.g. `-hv`), but it is relatively simple.

Acting on the `--verbose` during parsing is difficult.  The parser will act on the `-h` as soon as it parses it, displaying the message and exiting.  Thus any `-v` after `-h` will be missed.

Doing your own help after parsing is a viable option, if you turn off the regular help (thus preventing that print and exit action).  You will know the final values of both `help` and `verbose`.  But you will be responsible for your own exit.

Comment: ah, I get your point about alternate -hv, --verbose options.  Could you first do a dry call to the parse_args with a catch on SystemExit and examine the parser itself to see if it was in verbose mode?  Rather than checking for -v, -hv, etc...?  Possibly re-routing sys.stderr (or sys.stdout) for that initial call?

Comment: You could certainly do a 2 step parsing.  `add_help=False` and `parse_known_args` would be useful when running the first parser.  It might be easier to define two separate parsers than to modify one between runs, but that's an organizational detail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Although, I think you could make your answer more useful by showing some code, rather than offering general advice.

Comment: I often do provide tested examples, but I'm in the process of changing hard drives and don't have my usual setup available.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach.

## 1 Build the parser as you have done right now.

do a **pretty print** on the parser and figure out how epilog is stored in an option.  Or put a debug via **pdb.set_trace()** and use **dirs** and **vars** to look around.

i.e. figure out what the option data structure looks like with an epilog and without an epilog.

## 2 Instead of calling parser.parse_args() (standard use):

- look at `sys.argv` yourself.  If **-h and -v** leave the parser as is.
- if **-h but not -v**, adjust your parser before calling it to look as if it had no epilog.

## 3 call with parser.parse_args()

You could even build 2 parsers, one with epilog, one without and dynamically decide which one to call depending on `-v` flag.

p.s. actually, you want to check

```
if "-h" in sys.argv and not "-v" in sys.argv
```

Comment: `parser.epilog` is all you need to see and change the epilog.

Comment: You are basically suggesting that I parse sys.argv myself before calling the parser. I don't like this approach because any manual parsing is going to be inferior to what the parser does. The users are bound to run the app with things like -tulhv and it should dutifully show verbose help, which will not happen with what you're suggesting.

Comment: well... yes, there is that flaw.  I had not considered non-obvious ways to trigger the verbose mode.  still, the parsing smarts required are limited - you're not doing the whole thing the parser does, just catching verbose mode.  the other option is to trace how the parser reacts to parse_args (and the -h flag) and subclass the handling of epilog in your own class.  that might be considably less hacky than other approaches, including the one i suggested above.  i.e. i'd think in terms of lines of code added - writing your own help isn't likely to be very solid.

Comment: you also need to take into account -v (verbose) but without -h.  i.e. the user makes a mistake and parser outputs its help accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I also see the value of **verbose help** to add examples.

From [Python 2.7 argparse printing help](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#printing-help) and [Python 2.7 argument parser objects](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects) and comments above, I settled upon the following method:

```js
import argparse

. . .

if __name__ == '__main__':

    description_text = """
DESCRIPTION
    This command ...
"""

    epilog_text = """
    After execution, the user can ... 
"""

    example_text = """
EXAMPLES
    The following examples ...
"""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                  description=description_text,
                  epilog=epilog_text,
                  formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                  add_help=False)

    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', dest='help', action='store_true',
                        help='Show help and exit; see also --verbose')
    parser.add_argument('--usage', dest='usage', action='store_true',
                        help='Show usage and exit')
    . . .
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Display additional help or logging')

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    
    if arguments.usage:
        print(parser.format_usage())
        sys.exit(0)

    if arguments.help:
        help_string = parser.format_help()
        if arguments.verbose:
                help_string += example_text
        print(help_string)
        sys.exit(0)

    . . .
```

The result is a flexible output which supports `--help`, `--help --verbose` and `--usage` controls for the command.  Thanks to others above for the inspiration.